# How do I get two images to be next to each other at the bottom of my Div Box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an about page, I have text at the top and I want to have two images next to each other at the bottom, the problem I keep having is I can't figure out how to get them next to each other, they are at the bottom but they are on top of each other. I want them to be equal size both taking up 50% of the width of the Div box. I am a beginner at HTML and this is my first big project.

Here is my code

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: ultra;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #818181;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 250px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #252525;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #252525;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rcorners1 {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #fffafa;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  height: ;
}

img.img-1 {
  float: left;
}

img.img-2 {
  float: right;
}

.article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}

img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="Why Us.html">Why Us?</a>
  <a href="Meet The Team.html">Meet The Team</a>
  <a href="Gear.html">Gear</a>
  <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
  <a href="Products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="Satisfied Customers.html">Reviews</a>
  <a href="Location.html">Location</a>
  <a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <h1>GEAR</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="rcorners1">
      <div>Parapsychologists Peter Venkman, Raymond Stantz, and Egon Spengler were scientists working for Columbia University. After being called to the New York Public Library to investigate the recent paranormal activity, they encounterd a full-fledged ghost
        but she frightend them away. They lost their jobs at the university after that, so the trio established the Ghostbusters, a paranormal investigation and elimination service. They developed high-tech equipment to capture ghosts and they opened
        their business in a disused, run-down firehouse. In their first outing, Egon warns them never to cross the energy streams of their proton pack weapons, as this could cause a catastrophic explosion, and they captured their first ghost, Slimer,
        depositing it in a specially built containment unit in the firehouse basement. As the paranormal activity increased in New York City, they hired a fourth member, Winston Zeddemore, to cope with demand.</div>

      <div>The Ghostbusters were then called by cellist Dana Barrett, whose apartment was haunted by a demonic spirit, Zuul, a demigod worshipped as a servant to Gozer the Gozerian, a shape-shifting god of destruction and chaos. As the Ghostbusters investigated,
        Dana was possessed by Zuul, which declared itself the "Gatekeeper", and Louis was also possessed by a similar demon, Vinz Clortho, the "Keymaster". Both demons speaked of the coming of the destructive Gozer and the release of the imprisoned ghosts.
        The Ghostbusters took steps to keep the two apart.</div>

      Walter Peck, a lawyer representing the Environmental Protection Agency, had the Ghostbusters arrested for operating as unlicensed waste handlers and he orderd their ghost containment system deactivated, causing the explosion that released the ghosts and
      Louis/Vinz. The ghosts wreaked havoc throughout the city while Louis/Vinz advanced toward Dana/Zuul's apartment. After consulting blueprints of Dana's apartment building, the Ghostbusters learned that mad doctor and cult leader Ivo Shandor, declared
      humanity too sick to deserve existing after World War I, designed the building as a gateway to summon Gozer and bring about the end of the world.

      <div>The Ghostbusters were released from custody to combat the supernatural crisis. On the apartment building roof, Zuul and Vinz opened the gate between dimensions and they transformed into supernatural hellhounds. Gozer, in the form of a woman, is
        subdued by the team, disappearing entirely, as her voice echoes that the "destructor" will follow, taking a form chosen by the team; Ray inadvertently recalls a beloved corporate mascot from his childhood "something that could never, ever possibly
        destroy us" and the destructor arrived in the form of a giant Stay Puft Marshmallow Man that attacked the city. The Ghostbusters crossed their proton pack energy streams and fire them at Gozer's portal; the explosion closed the gate, destroys
        Stay Puft/Gozer, and frees Dana and Louis. The Ghostbusters were welcomed on the street as heroes. After these events we changed our company name to Bust A Ghost and we continued to work catching ghosts, and we still are today. Also these events
        were made in a documentry about us ca
      </div>
      <div class="article">
        <img src="Our Gadgets.jpg" class="img-1" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="article">
        <img src="Trap.jpg" class="img-2" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.article{
  display:inline-block;
  width:60%;
}` --> 60% + 60% = 120% > 100%

Comment: It didn't work, They are still on top of each other.

Comment: what didnt work ? :) I am showing your code where you have done wrong and where you need to correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this issue because you assigned `width: 60%` to each div and that makes more than 100% for both together. You have to make them 50% and instead of `display:inline-block`, make them `float:left` followed with a `clear:both`. Try this code.

```
<div class="article">
    <img src="Our Gadgets.jpg" class="img-1" alt=""/></div>
<div class="article">
    <img src="Trap.jpg" class="img-2" alt=""/>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

.article {
 float:left;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, the pictures are smaller but they are still on top of each other.

Comment: I have added the css styles, try adding them too

Comment: They are next to each other but they are not the exact same size

Comment: by exact same size do you mean height or width? because width must be equal but if you have different size image, their height might be different.

Comment: I mean height, the width is fine

Comment: to make the height equal for both the divs, either you have to use equal size image or you can add height to the <div class="article"> element along with overflow:hidden property. I would edit my answer to add this part.

Comment: Never mind but div box is overextending so the image height ends and the Div box is like 200px longer

Comment: I added the height of <div> element to be 100px, you can increase the height as your requirement.

Comment: I figured that out but as the above comment states the div box is overextending it should end with the images and be the exact height but it is going farther than that. It has something to do with the height of the <div> element.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.article{
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you can't have white spaces in image source (src="Our Gadgets.jpg"). User slash or underline instead.

HTML

```
<div class="images">
<img src="http://www.modafinilsale.com/data/out/789/231770955-random-desktop-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://www.modafinilsale.com/data/out/789/231770955-random-desktop-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.images img {
display: block;
width: 50%;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: They are not in the Div box also they are still on top of each other

Comment: It works because I tested it. If you have problems maybe is because some other styles are interfering.

Comment: If you want to have the images in independent divs, then set:

.divContainer1, .divContainer2 {
width: 50%;
display: block;
float: left;
}

and for the images inside,
.divContainer1 img, .divContainer2 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto
}